# Change a dropdown list in a page using R

Tags: javascript, r, forms, web-scraping

In this page https://english.mubasher.info/markets/EGX/stocks/IRAX/financial-statements
There is drop down list to change financial statements period presented, that I want to change to "annual budget" then scrape the financial figures after.

I used the following R code considering it as a form :

```
pgsession<-html_session("https://english.mubasher.info/markets/EGX/stocks/IRAX/financial-statements") 
pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
```

the result as follows :

```
<form> '<unnamed>' (GET javascript:;)
  <select> '' [0/1]
```

Any ideas !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page uses JS to change the output. All data is stored in the variable `midata.financialStatement`:
[image]
The next step is to convert this variable to the JSON string. Open Console and run:
`JSON.stringify(midata.financialStatement)`
[image]
Copy the result with the outer double quotes and save it to a .json file.
Read the file with `jsonlite::fromJSON()`.
The result is a JSON object read in R and you can extract the data from it:
[image]
You take it from here.
For example, the data for the Second Quarter is obtained by this:

```
purrr::map_dfr(1:3, function(i) data$periods$sections[[2]]$records[[i]])
```

Result:

```
                                               label values.2016 values.2017 values.2018 values.2019 values.2020
1                                       Total Assets 19072955288 33794300569 34844771073 34960374490          NA
2                                  Total Liabilities 14440797107 23808120010 25334580748 28815017851          NA
3    Total Owners' Equity & Minority Interest Equity  4632158181  9986180559  9510190325  6145356639          NA
4           Total Liabilities & Shareholders' Equity 19072955288 33794300569 34844771073 34960374490          NA
5                                 Net Income or Loss  -274642239   252218095   703016650  -249721710          NA
6                                       Gross Profit   277077388   957501209  1814861030   624842327          NA
7  Net Cash Flow from (Used In) Operating Activities  -950298536   292022267    36383940 -1153033283          NA
8  Net Cash Flow from (Used In) Investing Activities    22438364   -33157784    30697312   -84466835          NA
9  Net Cash Flow from (Used In) Financing Activities   600461061  -111949845  -868421362  1212066785          NA
10             Net Change In Cash & Cash Equivalents  -327399111   146914638  -801340110   -25433333          NA
```

**Update:**
To achieve the result with coding in R, you need the `V8` package:

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)
url <- "https://english.mubasher.info/markets/EGX/stocks/IRAX/financial-statements"
jscode <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//script[contains(., 'midata.financialStatement')]") %>%
  html_text(trim = T)
jscode <- stringr::str_sub(jscode, start = 8) 
ct <- V8::new_context()
ct$eval(jscode) # execute JS
data <- ct$get("financialStatement")
period <- 'Fourth Quarter' # change to the period you want here
idx <- match(period, data$periods$label)
period_data <- purrr::map_dfr(1:3, function(i) data$periods$sections[[idx]]$records[[i]])
```

This should work, but sometimes I find the data misses one or two sections.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer Could you share the full code, the idea i also want to know how to change the drop down list using httr/ rvest packages.